# Screen freeze after msg send upon Google login (Flutter Firebase Codelab Friendly Chat App)

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I'm half way through this codelab for [flutter firebase](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#5)

App loads fine, accepts input and then loads up the Google sign-in options (add account if one is not already logged in). After this the app freezes.

Here are some screenshots of the thrown exceptions:
message_codecs.dart line 514

> throw new PlatformException(code: errorCode, message: errorMessage, details: errorDetails);

Screenshot of Android Studio with new Flutter plugin running emulator: 
[image: AndroidStudioFlutterPluginEmulatorRuntimeOutput]

Screenshot while running on actual Nexus 5 phone:
[image: AndroidStudioFlutterPhoneError]

Here is the main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'dart:async';

const String _name = "GCom";
final googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();
final ThemeData kIOSTheme = new ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
  primaryColor: Colors.grey[100],
  primaryColorBrightness: Brightness.light,
);
final ThemeData kDefaultTheme = new ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.red,
  accentColor: Colors.orangeAccent[400],
);

void main() {
  runApp(new FriendlychatApp());
}

Future<Null> _ensureLoggedIn() async {
  GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
  if (user == null) user = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  if (user == null) {
    await googleSignIn.signIn();
  }
}

class FriendlychatApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "friendly chatty patch",
      theme: defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android
          ? kDefaultTheme
          : kIOSTheme,
      home: new ChatScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class ChatMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  ChatMessage({this.text, this.animationController});
  final String text;
  final AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SizeTransition(
        sizeFactor: new CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut),
        axisAlignment: 0.0,
        child: new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 15.0), //10 vertical depth from top of screen. height.
          child: new Row(
            crossAxisAlignment:
                CrossAxisAlignment.start, //distance vertical of avatar icon
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      right: 16.0), //0-36- move r of Icon  orig 16
                  child: new CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage:
                          new NetworkImage(googleSignIn.currentUser.photoUrl))),
              new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                    .end, //.start brings _name end to end of text vertical
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text(googleSignIn.currentUser.displayName, //_name
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead), //headline
                  new Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 5.0), //distance under _name 40
                      child: new Text(text +
                          "  whenever") // style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead),
                      ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new ChatScreenState();
}

class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<ChatMessage> _messages = <ChatMessage>[];
  final TextEditingController _textController = new TextEditingController();
  bool _isComposing = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        //can be different than title?
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("friendly chatty patchy codelab."),
          elevation:
              Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS ? 0.0 : 4.0,
        ),
        body: new Container(
            child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
          new Flexible(
              child: new ListView.builder(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            reverse: false, //true to place at bottom of screen.
            itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _messages[index],
            itemCount: _messages.length,
          )),
          new Divider(height: 1.0),
          new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
            child: _buildTextComposer(),
          ),
        ]))); //extra )?
  }

  @override
  Widget _buildTextComposer() {
    return new IconTheme(
      data: new IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
      child: new Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0), //distance from r
          child: new Row(children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: new TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                onChanged: (String text) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isComposing = text.length > 2; //>0
                  });
                },
                onSubmitted: _handleSubmitted,
                decoration: new InputDecoration.collapsed(
                    hintText: "send a message..."),
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
                margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                child: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
                    ? new CupertinoButton(
                        child: new Text("Send"),
                        onPressed: _isComposing
                            ? () => _handleSubmitted(_textController.text)
                            : null,
                      )
                    : new IconButton(
                        icon: new Icon(Icons.send), //whatever icon
                        onPressed: _isComposing
                            ? () => _handleSubmitted(_textController.text)
                            : null,
                      )),
          ]),
          decoration: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
              ? new BoxDecoration(
                  border:
                      new Border(top: new BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200])))
              : null),
    );
  }

  Future<Null> _handleSubmitted(String text) async {
    _textController.clear();
    setState(() {
      _isComposing = false;
    });
    await _ensureLoggedIn();
    // ignore: referenced_before_declaration
    void _sendMessage({String text}) {
      ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage(
        text: text,
        animationController: new AnimationController(
          duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          vsync: this,
        ),
      );
      setState(() {
        _messages.insert(0, message);
      });
      message.animationController.forward();
    }

    _sendMessage(text: text);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (ChatMessage message in _messages)
      message.animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Android monitor shows that the app is loading, launching Google login. It's only when I click on the google account that the 'unknown buffer' comes up.

```
   20 13:15:39.403 3342-3367/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-20 13:15:39.468 3342-3367/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

                                                 [ 10-20 13:15:39.469  3342: 3367 D/         ]
                                                 HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f629efd1ea0, tid 3367


                                                 [ 10-20 13:15:39.470  3342: 3367 W/         ]
                                                 Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
10-20 13:15:39.470 3342-3367/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
10-20 13:15:39.482 3342-3367/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7f629efe2220: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
10-20 13:15:39.489 3342-3367/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f629efe2220: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f629f08ec60)
10-20 13:15:39.504 3342-3367/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f629efe2220: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f629f08ec60)
10-20 13:15:39.519 3342-3342/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x7f629b407b20: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
10-20 13:15:39.533 3342-3342/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f629b407b20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f629b38bfa0)
10-20 13:15:39.632 3342-3361/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f629b407b20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f629b38bee0)
10-20 13:15:39.635 3342-3368/? I/flutter: Diagnostic server listening on http://127.0.0.1:35653/
10-20 13:15:39.719 3342-3368/? I/flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:45464/
10-20 13:16:16.163 3342-3367/com.yourcompany.gcodelab D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f629efe2220: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f629f08ec60)
10-20 13:16:23.166 3342-3367/com.yourcompany.gcodelab D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7f629efe2220: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7f629f08ec60)
10-20 13:16:23.166 3342-3367/com.yourcompany.gcodelab E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f629efe1640
```

Comment: Can you please add the full code you are currently using alongside the logs in the console as a code in your post?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can happen if Google Sign In is not enabled (can be done in the Firebase console or [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)), or the hash of the public key used to sign the APK was not uploaded to the Firebase console, or if the application identifier (e.g. com.example.myapp) is not set correctly in the Firebase console. I would suggest checking those three things to make sure they're done. It is a bit odd that you're not seeing any useful console logs, though.

Comment: Hi Colin, I've check those 3 things. Firebase has Google Sign-In, SHA-1, and the app identifier. Sometimes the app screen doesn't freeze but it just returns to the original state to accept messages and doesn't display what has already been input.

Comment: Am having this same problem. The app does not return values in the Firebase db